# Run VBA Function in selected sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write VBA code that will delete column B from all worksheets in the open workbook except for Sheet1. All these worksheets are on the right from Sheet1, and their names are as well stored as range in sheet1 in column AA. Moreover in each of these worksheets (apart from Sheet1) in column A have to be insert autonumbering (1.2.3. etc) beginning from cell A2 and going down. In each worksheet column headings are the same but number of rows is different depending on data included in each sheet. I dont know how to repeat this macro in every sheet.

Comment: Please, show us what have you done so far, and what code you have written so far.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop using the Worksheets collection contained in the ActiveWorkbook object:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet

For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Not sheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then

     Debug.Print sheet.Name

    End If

Next
```

When you're inside that loop the sheet object is just a normal Worksheet object and you can do anything you would normally do to the ActiveSheet.